Java: Need to read jackson.databind module, but it does not exist
I have a class MyClass inside java module com.example.mymodule, which needs to use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.
When trying to run the app, I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.example.MyClass (in module
com.example.mymodule) cannot access class
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper (in module
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind) because module com.example.mymodule
does not read module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

I tried adding requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind; into mymodule, but then I get the error "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind cannot be resolved to a module".
I am using Maven and I have the latest jackson-databind:2.18.0 in my dependencies. The jar itself doesn't contain module-info.java.
I also tried using requires jackson.databind; but then I get error:

java.lang.module.FindException: Module jackson.databind not found,
required by com.example.mymodule"


Verify that the jar is in the modulepath via Maven setup. The jar itself doesn't contain module-info.java, are you referring to your application? Note, jackson-databind does have a module-info.class under versions.9 and the readme specifies that Jackson 2.10 and above include module-info.class definitions so the jar is also a proper Java Module (JPMS). e.g. directive requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind in a modular application and the use of ObjectMapper.findModules().size() works without any error.

Can you show your module-info.java and pom.xml?

@Naman I was referring to jackson-databind-2.18.0.jar which does not contain module-info.class

Reading the answer, I believe the original question was missing out on a crucial information/tag i.e. Eclipse and as I said, the jar does contain module-info.class. You can verify that with jar xf /path/tojar which shall help extract the content.

So I was using jackson-databind version 2.18.0 and Eclipse did not find module-info.class in the jar. Downgrade to 2.17.2 solved the issue.
Apparently I am not the first one to encounter this issue.
